# MATLAB: How to select rows from dataset where nominal variables is greater than a certain frequency?

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a dataset like this in MATLAB:

```
stovdata = 

state    discipline       gender    avggradereceived
OH       Humanities       M         A            
TX       Communication    F         B               
CA       Philosophy       M         B               
CA       Anthropology     M         A+             
CA       Mathematics      M         B+             
NV       English          F         A-              
CA       Communication    M         B-             
MA       Sociology        M         A-             
OK       Anthropology     F         B-              
VA       Languages        F         A
```

I want to select all rows containing disciplines which have a frequency greater than 2.

So I am calling the `sortrows` function after tabulating the `stovdata` to get the descending order of frequencies in discipline:

```
>> sortrows(tabulate(stovdata.discipline), -2)

ans = 

'Anthropology'           [2]    [20]
'Communication'          [2]    [20]
'English'                [1]    [10]
'Humanities'             [1]    [10]
'Languages'              [1]    [10]
'Mathematics'            [1]    [10]
'Philosophy'             [1]    [10]
'Sociology'              [1]    [10]
```

Now I want a reduced dataset which looks like this:

```
new_stovdata = 

state    discipline       gender    avggradereceived
TX       Communication    F         B               
CA       Anthropology     M         A+             
CA       Communication    M         B-             
OK       Anthropology     F         B-
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `idx = [ans{:,2}] >= 2`

Comment: @RandomGuy I'm very new to MATLAB. I can understand that `idx` is a logical vector which is supposed to tell me which rows to select from the `ans` (I have no idea how to make this happen, though). But I need to select the rows from `stovdata` where the `discipline` values are `Anthropology` or `Communication`.

Answer (score 0):

For a given `n x m` cell array `tmp` in MATLAB executing something like `tmp{:,j}` or `tmp{i,:}` returns what is known as a [Comma Separated List](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). You can construct an array from the list just by using square brackets around it. For example:

```
>> tmp = num2cell(eye(3))

tmp = 

[1]    [0]    [0]
[0]    [1]    [0]
[0]    [0]    [1]

>> [tmp{:,1}]

ans =

 1     0     0
```

In this case you can use the following to get the logical indexing for all rows with freq >= 2 from your data as:

```
idx = [data{:,2}] >= 2;
```

You can use this `idx` to get the rows from the cell array as:

```
data_ = data(idx,:);
```

Comment: This does not work because in my case first column of `ans` is not `Cell`. So `>>>[ans{:,1}]` yields a concatenated string like `AnthropologyCommunicationEnglishHumanitiesLanguagesMathematicsPhilosophySociology`

Comment: That's why I used the second column in `idx = [data{:,2}] >= 2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for the most efficient solution. The following will do the job:

```
SortedData=sortrows(tabulate(stovdata.discipline), -2);
NumberOfRows=size(SortedData,1);
IndexItr=1;
for RowItr=1:NumberOfRows
    if SortedData{RowItr,2}(1)>=2
       IndicesOfRowsOfInterest(IndexItr)=RowItr;
       IndexItr=IndexItr+1;
    else
       break;
    end
end
```

PS: IndicesOfRowsOfInterest contains the indices of rows containing disciplines which have a frequency greater than 2.

Comment: I changed the i to RowItr. This works like a charm. Thanks! :)

Comment: Souradeep, I am glad it worked. Could you please accept the answer? :) thanks!